# Consume SOAP web service using REST POST method

Tags: web-services, rest, post, soap

I want to consume a simple SOAP web service using REST technology. I've heard it can be achieved using POST method. Just adding some headers to the request. Is it possible? How to do that? Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP considers different information in the headers/body than REST does, but it's all HTTP:

```
# Headers
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: <SOAPAction here>

# Body
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
 <soapenv:Header>
 .
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
 .
 .
 .
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You'll need to fill in the actual body with whatever the SOAP service expects (obviously) - that can be found in the WSDL if you don't have any sample requests available.

I found [this blog post](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/08/22/making-soap-requests-using-postman/) to be very helpful, even if you're making the call from some non-postman tool.

Comment: It looks Nice!! I'm going to check it right now!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SergioDavidRomero if that works for you, please accept the answer!